# Android Emulator Controll does not work?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, gps, adb

I would like to test GPS on google maps on android.

Standard google emulator is very slow and has problems with google maps.

Geanymotion is not always detected, even if it's connected there's problem with Emulator Control which is deactivated for standard device and genymotion even if it is connected, detected, selected proper device and application process.

I know there is no eclipse/studio issue but tested it on both with the same result.

Restarting adb from IDE or command line does not work either.

[image]

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Try to set your place in Geanymotion GPS controle in right side panel.

Comment: I want to test whole track, not only one point.